How can convert the dataframe into desired new dataframe effectively?
x is a dataframe:
x
                year  mar 31, 2024  mar 31, 2023
0         net income       306.000      524.0000
1  net income growth        -0.416       -0.0455
2      retained rate           NaN           NaN
3                 pe       419.930        0.0000

It's row index and column name:
x.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=4, step=1)
x.columns
Index(['year', 'mar 31, 2024', 'mar 31, 2023'], dtype='object')

I want the desired new dataframe with below formats:
new_x
     year          net income  net income growth  retained rate      pe   
0    mar 31, 2024       306.0             -0.416            NaN  419.93     
1    mar 31, 2023       524.0            -0.0455            NaN     0.0

     
new_x.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1, step=1)
new_x.columns
['year', 'net income', 'net income growth', 'retained rate', 'pe']

How can get the new dataframe effectively?
x.T
                       0                  1              2       3    
year          net income  net income growth  retained rate      pe   
mar 31, 2024       306.0             -0.416            NaN  419.93     
mar 31, 2023       524.0            -0.0455            NaN     0.0   

The transpose method can't work.

You have to set_index, transpose, rename_axis:
out = x.set_index('year').T.rename_axis(index='year', columns=None).reset_index()

Output:
           year  net income  net income growth  retained rate      pe
0  mar 31, 2024       306.0            -0.4160            NaN  419.93
1  mar 31, 2023       524.0            -0.0455            NaN    0.00

Or rename "year", then melt+pivot:
out = (x.rename(columns={'year': 'cols'})
         .melt('cols', var_name='year')
         .pivot(index='year', columns='cols', values='value')
         .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index() # optional
      )

Output:
           year  net income  net income growth      pe  retained rate
0  mar 31, 2023       524.0            -0.0455    0.00            NaN
1  mar 31, 2024       306.0            -0.4160  419.93            NaN

